# What will be the result of next function and array in main?

Tags: c, arrays, function

today i tried to do something new,but i didn't do that correct.Would anyone be able to do that and explain why is it so like that? Thank you in advance

```
#include<stdio.h>

void function(int a[],int n)/*The definition of function with void type,with parameters
int a[],int n */
{
  int i;// declared count,type integer//

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)//count goes from 0,to <n,and increment all time while goes//
      printf("%d",a[i++]);// printing on the screen integers (a[i],i=i+1)//
  printf("\n");// printing the newline //
}

main()
{
  int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}; // declaration of array with 7 elements //
  int n=5;// declaration of variable n type integer value of 5 //

  function(a,n) // calling the function with parametres a,n//
} // end of sequence //
```

In my case i got the result of the **1,2,3,4**,because i tought that the count goes from 1,to the one number less than n=5,but the IDE show the result of **135** ,i think the problem in my way is with counter...but all advices are welcome,thanks

Comment: You're incrementing `i` twice inside the loop.

Comment: you're incrementing i twice

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that is so stupid from me,i missed that, what a uselles question now i see,thanks

Comment: Note: Don't state the obvious in your comments. Such comments don't make your code anything better readable, but just add pointless noise. Write what you intend instead! If you have to comment every single line, your code is wrong.

Comment: And `main()` is an invalid signature and not even standard. Implicit `int` is not allowed!

Comment: @Olaf Ok i will listen your advice in the next post for the comments thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you are posting properly formatted valid C code.

Note that what you get is not one hundred and thirty five, but one, three, and five. You get that because you are incrementing the loop counter twice.
Here's a working, more readable version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int a[],int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int n=5;
    function(a,n); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the OP also wants a new line after each number. So braces in the for loop that would hod both printf() functions or mix it into a single printf("%d \n",a[i]); would look even nicer.

Comment: Thanks a lot,also i had a problem with newline i tought that the function will print on the screen numbers each one in newline but now i see that it will be mixed into the one printf

Comment: You're welcome. You can either do it in one statement, or do it like for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
@cornel.raiu turns out you're right :)

Comment: @Vlad Dinev Guessed so :)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
printf("%d",a[i++]);// printing on the screen integers (a[i],i=i+1)//
```

with

```
printf("%d",a[i]);// printing on the screen integers (a[i],i=i+1)//
```

in your code you were incrementing i twice. Once in the while and once in the a[i++]

Comment: I thought the counter will be incremented just ones.. thanks